# When piping a file in windows to a python script, my \r are deleting my characters

Tags: python, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

I have a file like this:

```
A\r
B\n
C\r\n.
```

(By \r I'm referring to CR, and \n is LF)

And this script:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(mode='rU'):
    print(line)
```

When I call `python script.py myfile.txt` I get the correct output:

```
A
B
C
```

But when I call it like this: `type myfile.txt|python script.py`, I get this:

```
B
C
```

You see? No more "A".

What is happening? I thought the `mode='rU'` would take care of every newline problem...

EDIT: In Python 3 there is no such problem! Only in Python 2. But that does not solve the problem.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Just for the sake of completeness.
- It happens also in Linux.

- Python 3 handles every newline type (\n, \r or \r\n) transparently to the
  user. Doesn't matter which one your file got, you don't have to worry.
- Python 2 needs the parameter mode='rU' passed to fileinput.input to allow it
  to handle every newline transparently.
  The thing is, in Python 2 this does not work correctly when piping content
  to it.
  Having tried to pipe a file like this:

  ```
  CR: \r
  LF: \n
  CRLF: \r\n
  ```

Python 2 just treats these two lines as just one line and if you try to print
every line with this code:

```
for i,line in enumerate(fileinput.input(mode='rU')):
    print("Line {}: {}".format(i,line), end='')
```

It outputs this:

```
Line 0: CR:
LF:
Line 1: CRLF:
```

This doesn't happen in Python 3. There, these are 2 different lines.
When passing this text as a file, it works ok though.

Piping data like this:

```
LF: \n    
CR: \r
CRLF: \r\n
```

Gives me a similar result:

```
Line 0: LF: 
Line 1: CR:
CRLF:
```

My conclusion is the following:

For some reason, when piping data, Python 2 looks for the first newline
symbol it encounters and then on, it just considers that specific character
as a newline. In this example Python 2 encounters \r as the first newline
character and all the others (\n or \r\n) are just common characters.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the `type` command because simply executing `type myfile.txt` produces:
`B
C
.` On the other hand you said it worked on Python3 so that's really puzzling.

Comment: I thought exactly that, and then it working in Python 3 got me upside down... now I don't know what to think.

Comment: I couldn´t find an answer, I just ended deleting any CR or LF with re.sub

Comment: Last `C` is not deleted; `\r` moves the cursor to the start of the line and it hides `C`.   try to `... |python script.py | od -c ` to see whia is going on.